# frank screenshot crashes with keyboard

Tags: crash, cucumber, automated-tests, frank

We have a textfield which we tap on in our cucumber functional test step.

we take screenshot after every step using this line:
frankly_screenshot("#{screenshot_file}”)

But when we have a number keyboard shown on tapping the textfield, above line crashes the app.

Anybody who faced similar issue ?

Sample code:

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
def self.take_screenshot(file_name = "img")
    time = Time.now.strftime("%F_%H-%M-%S")
    screenshot_file = "Screenshots/" + "#{file_name}-#{time}.png"
    frankly_screenshot("#{screenshot_file}")
    screenshot_file
  end
```

Comment: Is the language java?  Is the screenshot being taken in the `@Before hook? What does the code that you are executing look like?  Try catching the exception and posting the exception name and stack trace. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 as the title says, this is frank cucumber framework used to write automation tests. It is done at "after hook" and also i added some sample code. Hypothesis is keyboard shows up when we do the step of tapping on the textfield and so keyboard shows up and after that "after hook" crashes while taking snapshots. In cases were keyboard does not show up, screenshots are taken and it works fine.

Comment: My apologies. I meant to say `@After hook. Long day. I have never heard of a keyboard getting in the way of a screenshot. Take my advice and capture the exception.  Print the exception message and post it here.